# Alice and Bob Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, inequality, game-theory

> Alice has $n$ positive real numbers $a_1,a_2,.....,a_n$ such that $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq a_3.......\leq a_n$ and $a_{i+1}\leq 2a_i$ for all $i=1,2,3,4.....,n-1$. Alice suggested Bob to choose signs $'+'$ and $'-'$ such that $k=\pm a_1\pm a_2....\pm a_n$ satisfies $0 \leq k \leq a_1$.
>
> Can Bob always do that ?

I was wondering of how can I approach this problem ? Does anyone have any idea of how can I proceed ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a greedy algorithm?

Comment: GregMartin:  I don't see how the greedy algorithm can possibly help given that you don't know the specific values of the $a_i$.  Please explain.

Comment: In fact, if the sum $a_1+\dots+a_n$ is even, then $k=0$ should be possible.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein  These need not be integers.

Comment: @lulu You're right, it's only assuming all $a_i$'s are integers.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein  If $a_1=2$ and $a_2=4$ you can't get $0$.

Comment: @lulu Oh yes, all integers, even sum, and $a_1=1$, then $k=0$ should be possible.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein  Indeed, that follows from my proof below.  Take the number $k_1$ as in that proof.  We note that it is odd and lives between $0$ and $2$, hence it must be $1$.  Then $k_1-1=0$.

Answer (score 6):

Proof by Induction.  Trivially true for $n=1$ and for $n=2$ take $a_2-a_1$.

Suppose true for $n-1$.  Apply it to the chain $a_2≤\cdots≤a_n$ to get $k_1=\pm a_2+\cdots +\pm a_n$ with $0≤k_1≤a_2$.  But then one of $a_1-k_1$ and $k_1-a_1$ will work.